# TypeError: In a VueJS application deployed to a test server, all user interactions are blocked on specific page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue 2 application which runs fine locally. On deployment to test server, using the same branch and all settings, I'm getting the following error on a specific route. While on this route, all user interactions with the page are blocked.

How do I debug these obscure `chunk-vendors` errors, especially on a remote server without access to Vue devtools?

We cannot reproduce the error locally.

[image: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_wrapper')]

Comment: The first thing I would check is to find out how my application is built differently locally vs dev (npm scripts in package.json). I see many posts suggested to double check the click events to see if there is a click event that is running a function but the function is not defined, but this shouldn't be your case as you mentioned that your code works fine locally.

Comment: Click on the first source location in the stacktrace and try to figure out what part of the original source code is this. Then, place a breakpoint at this place or one statement before it, reload the page and try to reproduce the issue. The breakpoint will trigger, and will have an active callstack in DevTools. You can't solve this issue without some debugging.

Comment: App is working good for other pages?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I do that all the time running this locally, but this error is occurring in non-human-readable Babel-compiled JS running on a remote server.

Comment: You should be able to run this Babel-compiled JS locally before uploading them to the remote server. Or you could also upload your source-maps (at least temporarily) to the remote server and then the stacktrace will point to your unminified source code. Like I said above - there is no straight answer here, you will have to debug it.

Comment: @IVOGELOV The source-maps idea is a good one. This particular issue turned out to be due to conflicting deployments that I was not alerted to, but I'll keep this method in my back pocket. Thank you.